Regarding the issue of using ReactMarkdown to render React
My code:
function Article(props){
  console.log( "[debug] props.content is "+ typeof props.content);
  console.log( "[debug] props.content : "+ props.content);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.title}</h1>

      <ReactMarkdown children={props.content} />

    </div>
  );
async function BlogPost(){
  const article = await get_article_by_user_id('02');

  return (
    <div>
      <Nav />
      <AuthorInfo />
      <Tags />
      <Article title={article[0].title} content={article[0].content}  />
    </div>
  );
}
}

err:
[debug] props.content is string
[debug] props.content : **test**
Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
 ⨯ Error: Unsupported Server Component type: undefined
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
digest: "2642602426"
 ⨯ Error: Unsupported Server Component type: undefined
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
digest: "2642602426"

I want to know why "children={props. content}" has problems
If I use "tag", the same problem applies
<ReactMarkdown> {props.content} </ReactMarkdown>

What is the correct usage，This confuses me a lot
